# Android Notification Action PendingIntent.getBroadCast does not work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

My Android notification Action buttons are not working at all. I have the following code in my service, and the receiver is **NOT** registered in the manifest because it makes no change. I can send the broadcast from another activity, and it works great, but there is a problem somewhere.

Here are the PendingIntents that pair with the buttons

```
    Intent next = new Intent(getString(R.string.receiver_notification_media_change));
    next.setAction(NOTIFICATION_MEDIA_CHANGE_NEXT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, next, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent last = new Intent(getString(R.string.receiver_notification_media_change));
    last.setAction(NOTIFICATION_MEDIA_CHANGE_BACK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentLast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, last, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Notification:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(smallDrawableResId)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon1, "as", pendingIntentLast)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon2, "asdf", pendingIntentNext)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText("title")
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) //to an activity. Works great
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1));
```

Here is the BroadcastReceiver which is declared in the class below.

```
private BroadcastReceiver notificationMediaChanger = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        System.out.println("RECEIVEDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");

        if(action.equals(NOTIFICATION_MEDIA_CHANGE_NEXT))
            playNextSong();
        else if(action.equals(NOTIFICATION_MEDIA_CHANGE_BACK))
            playPreviousSong();
    }
};
```

OnCreate the receiver is registered

```
        registerReceiver(notificationMediaChanger, new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.receiver_notification_media_change))); //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()) appears to be equivalent.
```

And OnStop it is removed:

```
        unregisterReceiver(notificationMediaChanger);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action strings do not match.

```
Intent next = new Intent(getString(R.string.receiver_notification_media_change));
next.setAction(NOTIFICATION_MEDIA_CHANGE_NEXT);
```

For some reason, you are replacing one action string with another. I do not know why.

```
registerReceiver(notificationMediaChanger, new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.receiver_notification_media_change)));
```

Here, you are using the first action string. Your `Intent` has the second action string. These are presumably not the same.

Also:

- `LocalBroadcastManager` is not used by `PendingIntent`
- Unless the `Notification` is only on the screen while your activity is on the screen (which would be bizarre), you need to register your receiver in the manifest

Comment: You were right about the Strings! Thank you so much! I was using code from another example that had different Strings the way I had them and his receiver checked for the difference. Also, the Notification is paired to a background service so I actually ended up not registering it anyway :) Thanks again!

Comment: `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_ACTION_BTN_TEST))` on Service's context also doesn't work